# -webkit-tap-highlight-color highlights the previously clicked item rather than the one you are clicking

Tags: html, css

Within a `ul` element i have a list of anchor tags that represent social media icons like so :

```
<ul class="social-menu">
    <li class="social-item">
        <a href="#" title="Facebook" target="_blank">...</a>
    </li>
    <li class="social-item">
        <a href="#" title="Twitter" target="_blank">...</a>
    </li>
    <li class="social-item">
        <a href="#" title="Instagram" target="_blank">...</a>
    </li>
    <li class="social-item">
        <a href="#" title="Youtube" target="_blank">...</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

On Android mobile (the only OS that displays such behaviour by default)i'm noticing that when you click an item the highlight colour will appear correctly the first time. However, after that first time if you select a different icon the highlight appears over the previously selected icon.

I've tried explicitly declaring the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color`, ensuring the correct anchor tag has been clicked with some console logs for each item and even stripping back the content in the `<a>` tag to make sure that wasn't interfering but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check the yellow block on the top of this page :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color

You can try `:active` or `:active` and `:visited` instead.

```
a:active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

If you like my answer, please vote. I need some points to write comments :D If its not well answered, write the exact purpouse you need highlighting for. There wil be someone who will help for sure!